# Angular table prevent row click when column is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I click on table row, it should expand and show some extra data but when I click on a column, it should not expand the row, rather than perform column click.

I have simplified the code, please check the complete code example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vejae2?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="weightCicked(element)"> {{element.weight}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row (click)="rowclicked(row)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

When I click on `weight` column, `rowClicked` is also called, **how can I call only `weightCicked` method**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `$event.stopPropagation();` while binding `(click)` on your `td`

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="weightCicked(element); $event.stopPropagation();"> {{element.weight}} </td>
```